# Go to implementation (Arduino IDE/Visual Studio)?

Tags: arduino

I am browsing the code of an Arduino Sketch. It use a user library to define some functions. I installed the Arduino IDE extension for visual studio 2015. I can right click the .ino file over a function and go to the definition on the associated .h file but from there I haven’t been able to right click to go to the associated .cpp definition file. I even installed the “Go to implementation” extension for visual studio but it doesn’t work either.

There is any way to accomplish this on the Arduino IDE, Visual Studio or any other IDE?

Comment: Can you give us more details? I checked it out - I am available to use "Go to implementation".

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg Are you using the "Go to implementation" extension?

Comment: No, I have no extension installed like that